# Asyncio and Threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I am subscribed using asyncio to a socket that spits out data randomly (on db variable updates) and obviously I only receive these updates when the event loop is run.  I wanted to create a thread that would poll the event loop periodically (say every 3-5 seconds) to get updates even if I am not doing something specific with the event loop.

Would you recommend threading/mp or is there a better option for a background poll loop that asyncio has built into the lib that I am unaware of?

Comment: more information is needed to fully understand this question. what is the event loop? is there anything to do with the db ? codes preferred.

Comment: the asyncio.get_event_loop loop. The db is being updated and I am "subscribed" to receive updates over the socket connection for specific db updates.

I am wondering if I can just created a thread that is essentially:
while True:
    poll_loop()

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but anyhow here is my answer:

The eventloop should be running all the time. In your `main()` method you would typically get the eventloop instance by calling `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()`. Next you would add everything you need to it. Finally you would let it run forever by calling `loop.run_forever()`

There are tons of good docs available on asyncio programming in Python. This one, for example, is a pretty good read:
https://realpython.com/async-io-python/

You would usually not need to have multi threading in an asyncio service.